# Is there a name for position and dimension in the mathematics

Tags: geometry, terminology

I'm a Software Architect who looking for a corresponding term for position and dimensions of an object at the sametime.

Is there a word or term for that in geometry or analytic geometry?

Comment: The question is a bit vague since "position" and "dimension" both have very specific meanings already. Can you perhaps describe your problem a little?

Comment: Coordinates and side lengths? I second the request for more specificity.

Comment: @EuYu I'm building an computer application which watches dimensional and coordinate changes on an objects. My question is about naming this application. Is there a common name of this type of properties.

Comment: @B.D 'Coordinates and side lengths?' Yes that's true. My question is about nameing this kind of properties.

Comment: I tought only name 'geometrical' but it's too comprehensive!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no such term. Dimensionality would depend on the frame of reference and the attitude/orientation of the object. Is dimensionality taken with respect to the object, or to the reference frame?

In general, in mathematical modeling you can associate with an object of interest a concept known as a *state space*. This is simply a set of variables that describe properties of the object, e.g. mass, acceleration, position, rotation, and so forth. Most of the time, physical spatial dimensionality is not considered for rigid objects, because those dimensions don't change with respect to the object; however, for things like morphing structures, these *do* change, and *are* considered in the state space representation.

Comment: State space is fine enough. Thanx a lot.